# Dinamically created checkboxes, event handler and more - vb.NET asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to manage the checkall control in a gridview but I'm facing several problems.

This is my gridview control:

```html
    <asp:GridView ID="gvShow" runat="server" AutoPostback="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="224px" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="761px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataSourceID="sid_db">
      
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheckAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" OnCheckedChanged="chkCheckAll_CheckedChanged" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheck" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Scope" HeaderText="Scope" SortExpression="Scope" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Brand" SortExpression="Brand" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" SortExpression="Site ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Site Name" HeaderText="Site Name" SortExpression="Site Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CAP" HeaderText="CAP" SortExpression="CAP" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Master_ID" HeaderText="Master_ID" SortExpression="Master_ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol">
<HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>

        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

**First problem:**
The checkbox controls are dynamically created and I honestly have the feeling that I should create an event handler for those, but I don't know how to do it nor I know where to put/write that code. I just see those controls are not recognized once I try to reference them in my code.

**Second problem:**
Since I'm pretty much a newbie, I made a step back and tested with some junk code if I was able to have all the checkboxes dinamically checked at page load... here is my test... the result a complete failure, nothing happens. I even tried to put the code in the init event, but the result is the same.

```js
                For Each row As GridViewRow In gvShow.Rows
                    DirectCast(row.FindControl("chkCheck"), CheckBox).Checked = True
                Next
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with these problems.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. I had to change the code as follow:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gvShow" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="224px" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="761px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
      
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkSelectAll" runat="server" Autopostback="True" OnCheckedChanged="ChkSelectAll_CheckedChanged" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkSigleItem" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ChkSigleItem_CheckedChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Scope" HeaderText="Scope" SortExpression="Scope" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Brand" SortExpression="Brand" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" SortExpression="Site ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Site Name" HeaderText="Site Name" SortExpression="Site Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CAP" HeaderText="CAP" SortExpression="CAP" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Master_ID" HeaderText="Master_ID" SortExpression="Master_ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol">
<HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>

        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

And then:

```html
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Page.IsPostBack = False Then

            ''Set value for default SQL query
            Dim query As String
            query = "SELECT Sites.Master_ID AS Master_ID, Scopes.Name AS Scope, Brands.Extension AS [Brand], Sites.ID AS [Site ID], Sites.Name AS [Site Name], Sites.Address, Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name AS Country FROM Sites INNER JOIN Scopes ON Sites.scope_ID = Scopes.ID INNER JOIN Brands ON Sites.brand_ID = Brands.ID INNER JOIN Countries ON Sites.country_ID = Countries.ID"
            sid_db.SelectCommand = query

            gvShow.DataSource = sid_db
            gvShow.DataBind()

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub ChkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim a As Boolean = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gvShow.Rows
            Dim cbx As CheckBox = row.FindControl("ChkSigleItem")
            cbx.Checked = a
        Next

    End Sub
```